# Import JSON file in TypeScript declaration (*.d.ts files)

Tags: json, typescript, dynamic, types, import

I am writing a declaration file which should declare a global type and strict to a specific list of string phrases.
These string phrases are actually part of property keys in an object located in a JSON file.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to import a JSON file to a declaration file and process it using basic functions, like `Object.keys` and `Array.map`?
2. Yet, I wonder, if it is even possible to use JS array of strings to define a type in TS?

Let me give you a code example.

Let's say we have the following JSON file named `data.json`:

```
{
  "someList": {
    "#key1": {"a": 1, "b": 2},
    "#key2": "some value",
    "#key3": 1234
  }
}
```

Now, I want to create the following declaration file `global.d.ts`:

```
import data from './data.json';

declare global {
  type AllowedKeys = Object(data.someList).map(key => key.substr(1));
}
```

Basically, I need the type to be defined (dynamically as JSON file changes) like this:

```
type AllowedKeys = "key1" | "key2" | "key3";
```

Any help or at least guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: You can now use template string literals to infer sub-string starting from given character, like so:

```js
import data from "./data.json";
export type AllowedKeys = keyof typeof data["someList"] extends `#${infer K extends string}` ? K : never;
// This is equivalent to
// export type AllowedKeys = "key1" | "key2" | "key3"
```

---

You can have typescript infer a type from data in a json-file.

```js
import data from "./data.json";


export type AllowedKeys = keyof typeof data["someList"];
// This is equivalent to
// export type AllowedKeys = "#key1" | "#key2" | "#key3"
```

The resulting `d.ts` file looks like this:

```js
import data from "./data.json";
export declare type AllowedKeys = keyof typeof data["someList"];
```

<s>As far as I know, there's no way to manipulate string literals in typescript (i.e, removing the `#`).</s>

See those github issues :

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12940
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754